# How many $3$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,...,19,20\}$ have product divisible by $4$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Same question :- [Where am I overcounting?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953621/where-am-i-overcounting)

How many $3$ element subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,...,19,20\}$  are there such that the product of the three numbers in the subset is divisible by $4$?

---

**My attempt:-**

I divided this into broadly 2 cases :-

Case 1:-

Subsets containing atleast 1 number of type 4k :-

1. $4k, 4k, 4k$ =${5 \choose 3}$
2. $4k, 4k, 4k+1$ =${5 \choose 2}*{5 \choose 1}$
3. $4k,4k,4k+2$ =${5 \choose 2}*{5 \choose 1}$
4. $4k,4k,4k+3$ =${5 \choose 2}*{5 \choose 1}$
5. $4k,4k+1,4k+1$ =${5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 2}$
6. $4k,4k+1,4k+2$ =${5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 1}$
7. $4k,4k+1,4k+3$ =${5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 1}$
8. $4k,4k+2,4k+2$ =${5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 2}$
9. $4k,4k+2,4k+3$ =${5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 1}$

Case 2:- without any 4k type of number

1. $4k+2, 4k+2, 4k+2$ =${5 \choose 3}$

I cant figure out what all cases am I missing ?  I am getting 685 cases however total cases are 795

Comment: Try complementary counting instead. Now there are just two cases: All numbers are odd or two numbers are odd and one is even.

Comment: You missed $4k,4k+3,4k+3$,and $4k+2,4k+2,2k+1$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We use complementary counting. For a set to have the product of its elements not divisible by $4$, there are two cases:

1. All elements are odd. There are $10$ odd numbers, so there are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways here.
2. Two elements are odd and one is even, but not divisible by $4$. This is $\binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{10}{2}$.

Thus the answer is $\binom{20}{3}-\binom{10}{3}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{2}=\boxed{795}$.

Answer (score 5):

Although complementary counting provides the most elegant approach, the approach taken by the OP (i.e. original poster) is still viable.

---

Case 1: At least one number that is a multiple of $~4.~$

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{20}{3}~$ ways of choosing three numbers, and there are $~\displaystyle \binom{15}{3}~$ ways of choosing three numbers, none of which is an element in $~\{4,8,12,16,20\}.$

Therefore, the Case 1 enumeration is

$$\binom{20}{3} - \binom{15}{3} = 685.$$

---

Case 2: None of the numbers are a multiple of $~4.~$

So, you either have exactly two even numbers, none of which is a multiple of $~4,~$ or three such even numbers.

Case 2a: Exactly two even numbers, neither of which is a multiple of $~4.~$

So, you have exactly one element from $~\{1,3,5,\cdots,19\},~$ and exactly two elements from $~\{2,6,10,14,18\}.$

So, the Case 2a enumeration is

$$\binom{10}{1} \times \binom{5}{2} = 100.$$

Case 2b: Exactly three even numbers, neither of which is a multiple of $~4.~$

You then have exactly three elements from  $~\{2,6,10,14,18\}.$

So, the Case 2b enumeration is

$$\binom{5}{3} = 10.$$

---

Final Total:

$$685 + 100 + 10 = 795.$$